# What underlying semantic notions explain the etymology of 'quā'?

Tags: etymology

> [ [Source :](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/qua#Etymology_1) ] Etymology 1
>
> Adverb declined from [quī](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui#Latin).
>
> Adverb
>
> quā (not comparable)
>
> 1. On which side, at or in which place, in what direction, where, by
>      what way (qua...ea...)
> 2. as; in the capacity or character of
> 3. In
>      so far as
> 4. In what way, how, by what method; to what degree or extent

I am conjecturing that 1 and 4 have close Semantic Fields, and both originate from the adverb quī per the above. But if so, then I find strange that 1 and 4 were enumerated the farthest from each other: they should have been 1 and 2.

Anyhow, how did 1 + 4 semantically shift to mean 2 and 3?

Comment: I don't think the numbering is very important. It is hard to see what the listed meanings mean exactly, because no examples are given. I am not sure if there has ever been a shift from 1&4 to 2&3; it may just be that they are independent developments. It seems that many uses of *qua* can be explained by assuming an implicit feminine noun in the ablative, like *via*. I see *qua* mainly as an ablative of a pronoun being reanalyzed as an adverb.